# Flat-list doesn't show any data in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

My flatlist doesn't anything data. I am using opentable Api and React `useState` and `useEffect`. I want to see data on my flatlist.

it's my code

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCity()
    }, [])

    const fetchCity = async ()=>{
        let response = await axios.get('https://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/cities')
        setMyCityList(response)
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(response.data.cities)
        console.log(response.data.count)
    }



    const renderCity = ({item})=>{
        console.log("merhaba")
        return (
            <CityItem  mycities={item.data.cities} />

        )
    }

    const searchCity =(text)=>{
        console.log(text)
    }
    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <View>

                <Searchbar placeholder="şehir arayın" onChangeText ={searchCity} />
                {loading ?
                    <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
                    </View>
                    :
                    <FlatList

                    keyExtractor = {(item,index)=> index.toString()}
                    data={myCityLİst}
                    renderItem={renderCity}
                />}
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
export {listCity}
```

I can see data on console but can't see on flatlist

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your Flatlist with the following code. since, you need to pass the array list to props data.

```
<FlatList
   keyExtractor = {(item,index)=> index.toString()}
   data={myCityLİst.data.cities}
   renderItem={renderCity}
 />
```

or

you can just update your `setMyCityList(response)` hooks with `setMyCityList(response.data.cities)`